# Find the 4th point in this system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$x(t), y(t)$ is a solution to the system of differential equations

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=ax+by$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=cx+dy$$

The solution lies on a straight line.  What is the value of $y(10)$ if $y(0)=5$, $x(0)=6$, and $x(10)=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution lies on a straight line, meaning that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is constant. At $t = 0$, it is given by$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{cx(0) + dy(0)}{ax(0) + by(0)} = \frac{6c + 5d}{6a + 5b}$$At $t = 10$, it must be the same as the one at $t = 0$.$$\Rightarrow \frac{cx(10) + dy(10)}{ax(10) + by(10)} = \frac{2c + y(10)d}{2a + y(10)b} = \frac{6c + 5d}{6a + 5b}$$Naturally, we see that $y(10) = 5/3$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** You have $\vec{u(t)} = (x(t),y(t))^T$ and $u' = Au$ where $$A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.$$

The solution to the system is given by $\vec{u}(t) = e^{tA} \vec{u}(0)$, can you solve and plug in your conditions?